# Как получить доступ к объекту gameObject из OnGUI?

Tags: unity3d

К gameObject  добавлен префаб и  скрипт с OnGUI.

Как получить доступ к объекту gameObject из OnGUI?

Или к index (index от TowerPrefab)?

Добавляется к gameObject   Скрипт с надписью label

```
 public class TowerPrefab : MonoBehaviour
    {
         public  int index;
public static void ViewTowerPrefab()
{
    foreach (TowerPrefab i in TEMP.TOWER.LIST_TOWER_PREFAB)
    {               
        var prefab = Resources.Load(i.resources_load);
        GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject; //создаем объект  
        go.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        go.transform.position = new Vector3(i.vector3.x, i.vector3.y, i.vector3.z);

        //Добавляется Скрипт с надписью label
        go.AddComponent<LabelT>();
    }
```

.

```
public class LabelT : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void OnGUI()
        {            
            Vector3 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position); //Находим позицию объекта на экране относительно мира
            Vector3 cameraRelative = Camera.main.transform.InverseTransformPoint(transform.position); //Получаем дальность объекта от камеры
            if (cameraRelative.z > 0) //если объект находится впереди камеры
            {               
                var dy = 150;
                var mdy = dy - 10;

                //Это работает
                GUI.Label(new Rect(screenPosition.x, Screen.height - screenPosition.y - mdy, 200f, 20f), this.name);
                mdy = dy - 10;
                //??? Как получить поле
                var i = gameObject.GetComponent<TowerPrefab>() as TowerPrefab;
                //Не работает
                //Не находит gameObject
                //NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
                //Не работает
                var ii = gameObject.GetComponent<TowerPrefab>().index;
                GUI.Label(new Rect(screenPosition.x, Screen.height - screenPosition.y - mdy, 200f, 20f), i.name);               

            }

        }

}
```

.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

.

```
public static void AddTowerPrefabInListTowerPrefab(int num)
        {
            SwitchTowerPrefab();

            GameObject gao = new GameObject("tower__" + num);
            gao.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            var unit1 = gao.AddComponent<TowerPrefab>();

            //
            unit1.resources_load = TEMP.TOWER.resources_load;
            var prefab = Resources.Load(TEMP.TOWER.resources_load);
            unit1.prefab = prefab;
            //
            unit1.index = num;
            //unit1.transform.position = GetVector3ForTowerPrefab(num);


            TEMP.TOWER.LIST_TOWER_PREFAB.Insert
            (
                num,
                unit1
            );
```

Comment: А у вас `TowerPrefab` находится не на том же объекте, что и `LabelT`, вот он его и не находит. Разве нет?

Comment: Похоже да. Пытаюсь объединить

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю что вы хотите сделать) у вас `TowerPrefab` должен быть один для всех или для каждого свой. если для каждого свой, то почему у вас TowerPrefab инстанциирует другие TowerPrefab. А если один на всех, то какой смысл в index? Если хотите всем только добавить `label`, то зачем инстанциировать новые?

Comment: index для теста.
Да. TowerPrefab должен быть один для всех и храниться в списке для более удобного доступа

Comment: Если хотите всем только добавить `label`, то зачем инстанциировать новые?

Comment: В одном из случаев (AddTowerPrefabInListTowerPrefab) создаются объекты (видны в иерархии) но префаб пустой падает сквозь сцену. Второй (ViewTowerPrefab) нормально ставится на сцену. Второй сделан для исправления ошибки первого но при этом берёт часть данных из первого. А вообще есть ещё и другой класс для хранения данных. У них индексы положения в списках идентичны. А вообще задача стоит в хранении данных (свойств) объекта и префаба с возможность сохранять данные в файл и передавать через сцену. Приходится делать костыль.

Comment: Чтоб через сцену проносить достаточно делать `DontDestroyOnLoad` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html  например это может быть какой-то GameManager, использующий паттерн Синглтон и который в себе хранит некоторые данные, используемые в каждой сцене (музыка, префабы, картинки и прочее).... может быть вам покопать в эту сторону?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как получить доступ к объекту gameObject из OnGUI?

Если скрипт LabelT висит на том же объекте что и TowerPrefab, тогда:

```
 int index = this.GetComponent<TowerPrefab>().index;
```

Но лучше дополнительно проверить а есть ли этот скрипт:

```
TowerPrefab tp = this.GetComponent<TowerPrefab>();
if (tp != null) 
{
    int index = tp.index;
}
```

Если нет, тогда вам нужно сначала найти этот объект:

```
TowerPrefab tp = GameObject.Find("имя объекта").GetComponent<TowerPrefab>();
```

А лучше чтобы 100 раз не искать объект, при инициализации нового объекта с LabelT передавать TowerPrefab параметром например.

**UPD**
Если Вы хотите иметь один список на все приложение для доступа к TowerPrefab, можно создать либо static class, либо singleton со списком и при инициализации закинуть туда нужные префабы.

Поскольку ЮниЮзеры обычно пользуются редактором для перетаскивая префабов, а статик классы нельзя повесить на объекты, то лучше использовать Singleton:

```
public class TowerPrefs : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static TowerPrefs _instance;
    public static TowerPrefs Instance {get {return _instance; }}

    //таким образом приватное поле будет видно в инспекторе
    [SerializeField] private TowerPrefab[] storage;

    //Инициализация единственного экземпляра, если будет два или более 
    // объектов с этим скриптом, то все кроме одного самоуничтожатся.
    void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance == null){
            _instance = this;
        }else{
             Destroy(this.GameObject);
        }
    }

    //метод для доступа к объектам списка
    public TowerPrefab GetTowerPrefab(int index)
    {
         return storage[index];
    }
}
```

Далее вешаете этот скрипт на некий объект, закидываете префабы и получаете доступ к ним откуда угодно:
     TowerPrefs.Instance.GetTowerPrefab(12);

Comment: Если вы посмотрите комментарии под вопросом - то там написано, что у  ТС не так...ваши `GetComponent` и `!=null` не помогут....... p.s. главное особо не увлекаться `Find` - это очень тяжелая операция.

Comment: Если ТС желает сделать один единый список на все приложение, в таком случае можно создать Static class либо Singleton, при инициализации закинуть туда префабы и уже из них их вытаскивать по индексу.